# "Conical Closure" of an Ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraically closed field and let $I\subsetneq\mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a radical ideal. We can send $I$ to a **homogeneous radical ideal** in three steps:
$$I \mapsto V(I) \mapsto \mathrm{Cone}(V(I)) \mapsto I(\mathrm{Cone}(V(I))).$$
Here $V(I)\subseteq\mathbf{F}^n$ is the zero set of the ideal $I$, $\mathrm{Cone}(V(I))\subseteq\mathbf{F}^n$ is the cone over this set, i.e., $$\mathrm{Cone}(V(I))=\{\lambda\mathbf{p}: \mathbf{p}\in V(I), \lambda\in\mathbb{F}\},$$ and $I(\mathrm{Cone}(V(I)))$ is the ideal of polynomials that vanish on this cone. (This final ideal is homogeneous since it is the ideal of a conical set and it is radical by the Nullstellensatz.) Let us define $\mathrm{Cone}(I):=I(\mathrm{Cone}(V(I)))$.

Question: How is $\mathrm{Cone}(I)$ described in terms of $I$? If $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ then is it true that $\mathrm{Cone}(I)$ is generated by the homogeneous parts of the polynomials $f_i$?

Comment: $I=(y-x^2)\subset k[x,y]$ shows your guess about generation by the homogeneous parts isn't correct - it's conical closure is the zero ideal, as the closure of the space of lines through the parabola is the whole plane. There may be some helpful material in the literature about the join variety - what you're doing here is asking what the ideal of the join variety of $V(I)$ and the origin is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondence between ideals and closed subsets reverses inclusion. Therefore, the expected ideal should not be the ideal $I^+$ generated by homogeneous parts of generators of $I$, as such ideal would contain $I$, but rather
$$\mathrm{Cone}(I)=I^{-}:=(\{f \in I\; |\;f \text{ is homogeneous}\}) \subseteq I.$$
Indeed, as $I^-$ is the biggest homogeneous ideal contained in $I$, $V(I^-)$ is the smallest conical subset containing $V(I)$, which is $\mathrm{Cone}(V(I))$.

(If you prefer to talk strictly about varieties, i.e. $I$ is assumed to be a radical ideal, note that then $I^-$ is radical too, so it works out.)